# Why am I getting three "Cross-Origin Request Blocked" messages

Tags: svelte, cross-origin-read-blocking

I have a Svelte application and I am trying to render data from the API but I keep on getting three error messages.

The code works properly on node but not on Svelte.

Below is the Svelte code:

```
<script lang="ts">
  import { onMount } from "svelte";

  let word = [];
  onMount(async () => {
    const response = await fetch(
      "https://random-words5.p.rapidapi.com/getMultipleRandom?count=1&wordLength=5",
      {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          "X-RapidAPI-Key": "KEY",
          "X-RapidAPI-Host": "random-words5.p.rapidapi.com",
        },
      }
    );
    word = await response.json();
    console.log(word);
  });
</script>

<p>{word}</p>
```

And below are the error messages:

> ross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://random-words5.p.rapidapi.com/getMultipleRandom?count=1&wordLength=5. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ does not match ‘https://localhost:5173’).

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://random-words5.p.rapidapi.com/getMultipleRandom?count=1&wordLength=5. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.

How do I get my code to render out the data from the API in Svelte?

Answer (score 1):

The `CORS` issue occurs when you try to fetch a resource from a `local` environment, this is the case when you run your app in `dev` mode.

I use the [CORS Unblock](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cors-unblock/lfhmikememgdcahcdlaciloancbhjino?hl=en-US) extension to fix the issue, give it a try.